# Is it possible to find the seed for GoogleTest to run a specific order if the order is known?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have been given a list of 25 tests and a order to run them in that is supposedly causing a failure in the last test. Unfortunately the tool that was used to find this failure does not save the seed that was used by GoogleTests shuffle to trigger this order.

So I can of course just run the tests with shuffle and repeat a huge number of times until this order is triggered, but there is quite a lot of permutations to work through. As far as I can tell there isn't a way to just say "Hey run these tests in this order" with GoogleTest aside from knowing the seed to trigger the order.

I'm hoping there might be a way to find that seed without actually running the tests - ideally something that could be given the desired order and output the seed, but really just something that given the gtest_filter value just dumps out massive amounts of potential test orders and the seeds that trigger them would be fine.

Is there any options out there, or I'm I just running with shuffle until I get it?

Comment: Ideally, the *tester* identifies the (a) seed that trips the problem, then submits that as part of their repro. Or... are *you* the tester ? Ouch.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ideally yes, that is what happens. Unfortunately they did not (more accurately they were given a tool that didn't give them that data, but once they had the failure and the order then that was technically enough to make it no longer their job). I am pushing to get the tool fixed or not used anymore, but that will only help me in the future.

Comment: If you specify `--gtest_shuffle`, Google Test will [print](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/25ad42aabeaba6227f37795cdd2752e128e83827/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L3450) the random seed used for the test run. You can then reproduce the shuffle by specifying the seed to use with the `--gtest_random_seed` flag. So all you need is access to the logs from the failed tests.

Comment: @VladLosev unfortunately there is no logs, the tool used dumped the default output to /dev/null, only saving the test order. Yes it is really dumb for the tool to do that. No I don't know why it does. Now that I am aware of it I'm pushing for it to get changed, but that will only help in the future. Thanks though, this would be a very helpful answer with any normal testing tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such option to specify the order of the tests.

However, By default  (i.e. if `--gtest_shuffle` is not enabled), they run in the declaration order.

I can think of three ways of achieving what you want:

1. Use your favorite scripting language (e.g. bash, python, nodejs, etc) and regular expressions to modify the original order of the tests to your desired order and create a new test file which then you run without `--gtest_shuffle`.
2. Hack into Google test's source code. You can modify [the shuffle function](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/25ad42aabeaba6227f37795cdd2752e128e83827/googletest/src/gtest.cc#L3112) to shuffle the code in the order that you want.
3. Look into [Registering tests programmatically](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#registering-tests-programmatically). I think you might be able to register your tests one by one in the order that you want, and I think Googletest will observe that order. But this also requires processing your original test file.

Obviously, none of these methods are ideal, but they might work for a one-off experiment to find the order that you want.

Comment: I added a third option with registering tests programmatically.

Comment: Ok, that is pretty much what I expected, but good to have confirmation, and thanks for listing the best options you can think of, hopefully I can use one of them to make the process slightly easier.

Comment: `However, By default..., they run in the declaration order.`
This seems to contradict what's mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#shuffling-the-tests).
`By default, GoogleTest uses a random seed calculated from the current time.`